# Complex model binding in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

Hi I am new to Angular Js. I have a model like below

```
$scope.data = {
            FocusOn: "",
            Filters: [
                {
                    FilterName: "",
                    FilterValue: ""
                }
            ],
            Range: {
                From: "",
                To: ""
            }
        }
```

Below is my simple HTML,

```
<select ng-model="data1.Filters.FilterName" ng-options="day for day in days"></select>
                <input type="text" ng-model="data1.Filters.FilterValue"/>
                <button ng-click="addField()">Add Field</button>
```

JS is like below

```
$scope.data.Filters.push(data1);
```

But it is not pushed into the arrary. What went wrong and How to use complex models in Angular Js.

Can any one help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

here http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/10708/

Use

```
$scope.data.Filters.push($scope.data1);
```

data1 also lies in the scope of the controller.